# NullReferenceException when doing a Join using Entity Framework, but only when deployed

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have the worst problem I've ever encountered today. When I deploy a WCF service to live, it throws and logs a `NullReferenceException` when trying to do a join. The code for the join is this:

```
var myInfo = __myContext.Dates
    .Join(_myContext.Times, d => d.SomeID, t => t.SomeID, (d, t) => new { d, t })
    .Where(c => c.d.DateType == "Date of Birth")
    .ToList();
```

As the code is running remotely, I'm unable to work out what is null. I deployed it to an Edge environment for testing, and get the same issue. The spanner in the works is the following:

- Works fine on my local machine.
- Works fine on my local machine when I set the webconfig to use the Edge database. (I really thought this would let me solve it)
- SQL Profiler shows a standard sql query join query (nothing unusual) which when ran independently executes with no issue.

I am completely stumped and am looking for debugging suggestions as much as anything else. Short of installing Visual Studio on my remote server, what else can I do?

I understand there is something called intellitrace which I might be able to use, however there are no good tutorials explaining if this will help or how to get it working (the MSDN pages are atrocious).

At this point anything is welcome as a suggestion. Thanks.

Some more info:

It seems to be having an error when it pulls back certain entities, eg:

`var myobjects = _context.SomeTable.ToList();` might error, whereas `var myobjects = _context.SomeTable.Select(c => new { ....... }.ToList();` works okay. I still can't explain why it would only do this on a remote server and locally, even when connected to a remote database, it would not.

Comment: can you debug this on any environment? have you tried running this and debugging this on your local..? make sure that if you are running it locally / Remote that you do not have any hard coded names make sure that the Remote server has the same database Context i.e setup that you have on your local..`based on the single line of code it's really hard to determine what's working or not working` please provide more code if possible

Comment: I can debug locally, but it doesn't have any errors and works fine, whether I use my local database or remotely connect to Edge where it is not working - this seems to rule out the DB. Also I cannot see anything that could actually throw a null reference exception on that line. Putting a throw NotImplementedException on the line before it triggers that exception instead, so it's definitely that line.

Comment: Are your `ID` properties Nullable? Maybe they are throwing the exception?

Comment: They are nullable (don't ask!), but there are no entries in the database that have a value of null, and the join works correctly when I run the generated SQL myself. In addition, it works locally when remotely using the database on the broken server.

Comment: also are you wrapping any of your code in a `try{}catch{}` perhaps there is an exception and during debug the exception is being consumed and not thrown check your code where ever you are creating an Instance of an object, make sure that you either `new` it or `Initialize` it first once again hard to tell without seeing your code

Comment: The code is running via interception, and any exception generated by the intercepted method is logged into the database. Perhaps I can add some additional debugging around that?

Comment: Turn on all exceptions under visual studios debug -> exceptions menu item. See if that gives you extra exceptions to fix locally that could be failing silently on live.

Comment: I have them all on already unfortunately, nice idea though!

Comment: It looks like EF context initialization error, make sure connection string is being read properly (if you are using Azure websites, it overrides and clear connectionStrings collection).

Comment: What initializes `__myContext`? No other part of the code shown will throw a NRE because `c.d` is translated into SQL - unless the exception is thrown from within EF? If not, log `"__myContext is null = " + (__myContext == null)` on the line before this executes...

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar issue and the fix was to simply set ProxyCreationEnabled to false before doing the call:

```
 _context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

 var myInfo = __myContext.Dates
    .Join(_myContext.Times, d => d.SomeID, t => t.SomeID, (d, t) => new { d, t })
    .Where(c => c.d.DateType == "Date of Birth")
    .ToList();
```

Note that in my case, I was able to determine that it was not actually the query itself that was throwing error, but rather it was when trying to pass the result to the client via WCF.